# C access struct in struct

Tags: c, struct

A project in C is being forced upon me. I do not have much C knowledge, but I'm assuming the answer is simple.

```
struct s1 {
  char *text;
  int num;
};

struct s2 {
  struct s1 vals[5];  
  int numbers;   
};
```

Assume s2 is already populated. How do access num from s1? I was assuming I would do something like

```
struct s2 temp;
//temp is populated somehow, doesn't matter in the case
printf("%d\n", temp.vals[0]->num);
```

but that doesnt work. Any suggestions?

Comment: *"This question was caused by a simple typographical error."* **VTC**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `temp.vals[0].num`.  The `->` operator can only be used if you are using a pointer to a struct.  You are using a struct directly.